# Condition for perfect packing of ellipse with circles along the major axis

Tags: geometry, reference-request, circles, conic-sections

The question was inspired by 
[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3593718/122782).

Condition for perfect packing of ellipse with circles:
$n$ circles can be perfectly packed
along the major axis of the ellipse with semi-axes $a,b\quad$
iif

\begin{align} 
\frac ba&=\sin\frac{\pi}{2\,n}
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Here "perfectly packed" means that 
the chain of circles with the centers on the major axis
is inscribed into the ellipse, 
and the radii of the circles at both ends
agree with the curvature of the ellipse 
at the ends of the major axis.

Condition \eqref{1} works for both odd (ex. $n=7$)

[image]

and even $n$ (ex. $n=8$)

[image]

Question:

Is this a well-known condition? Any reference?

---

**Addendum**

General formula for the radius of 
$k$-th circle 
in a chain of $n$
perfectly packed circles along the 
major axis of the ellipse
\begin{align}
r_k&=a\,\sin\frac{\pi}{2\,n}\,\sin\frac{(2\,k+1)\,\pi}{2\,n}
,\quad k=0,\dots,n-1
,
\end{align}
where $a$ is the major semi-axis, and the location of the center of $k$-th circle is found as
\begin{align}
O_k&=
F_1\cdot\cos^2 \frac{(2\,k+1)\,\pi}{4\,n}
+F_2\cdot\sin^2 \frac{(2\,k+1)\,\pi}{4\,n}
,
\end{align}
where $F_1,F_2$ are the focal points of the ellipse.

Distances from $F_1,F_2$ to the tangent point 
of the $k$-th circle with the ellipse
are

\begin{align}
|F_1T_k| &= 2\,a\,\sin^2\frac{(2\,k+1)\,\pi}{4\,n}
,\\
|F_2T_k| &= 2\,a\,\cos^2\frac{(2\,k+1)\,\pi}{4\,n}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\cos\angle T_kO_kF_2&=
\frac{\sin\frac{k\,\pi}n-\sin\frac{(k+1)\,\pi}n}
{\sin\frac{k\,\pi}n+\sin\frac{(k+1)\,\pi}n}
.
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: It's neater to write the condition in terms of cosine: $$e = \cos\frac{\pi}{2n}$$ where $e$ is, of course, the eccentricity. :) Upon realizing this, I re-wrote [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3593952/409) to the circle-chain question, replacing the cumbersome $\arctan(b/c)$ with $\arccos e$. I also wrote an Addendum to explicitly derive your perfectly-packable condition.

Comment: @Blue: Nice, +1

Comment: Regarding your Addendum: From my answer, we can deduce your formula for the $k$-th radius, and also that the $x$-coordinate of the center of the $k$-th circle is $x_k=a\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}$. Note that (literally) together, these give $$x_k+r_k = a\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}$$ These values are the $x$-coordinates points of tangency of the chained circles. Coincidentally, they're *also* the $x$-coordinates of the vertices of a regular $2n$-gon whose circumdiameter is the ellipse's major axis. Nifty! ... I wonder if this connection leads to a more-direct proof.

Comment: @Blue: Yes, the connection with regular polygon is fascinating.
Btw, your comments already weight the answer.