# Packing parabola with the chain of internally tangent circles

Tags: reference-request, circles, conic-sections

[image]

Related to the question
[Condition for perfect packing of ellipse with circles along the major axis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3594700/122782)

An attempt of "perfectly pack" a parabola
$x=ay^2$
as a special king of ellipse with eccentricity 1 results in
a packed sequence of circles

\begin{align} 
r_0&=\frac1{2a}
,\quad
r_1=3r_0
,\quad
r_2=5r_0
,\quad \dots
,\quad
r_n=(2n+1)r_0
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

where $r_0$ is the starting circle,
internally tangent to parabola at its vertex,
which agrees with the curvature at the vertex.

**Question:** Is there any known reference
where this property of parabola is mentioned/discussed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a paper that came out in 2019: Giovanni Lucca, [*Integer sequences, Pythagorean triplets and circle chains inscribed inside a parabola*](https://ijgeometry.com/product/giovanni-lucca-integer-sequences-pythagorean-triplets-and-circle-chains-inscribed-inside-a-parabola/).  The PDF is [here](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2.-22-31.pdf).

> **Abstract:** In this paper we consider the infinite chains of mutually
> tangent circles that can be inscribed inside a parabola and we derive
> the expressions for the radii and centres coordinates; moreover, we
> establish the conditions that relate the circle chains to Pythagorean
> triplets and to certain integer sequences.