# Triangle inscribed and circumscribed gap-filling radii sequences distinct?

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, packing-problem, osculating-circle

Staring with an equilateral triangle $\Delta$, inscribe a circle, then in the gaps,
inscribe other circles, ad infinitum.
Similarly, inside the circumscribed circle but outside $\Delta$,
continue to fill in every gap with a touching circle:

---

[image: InscribedCircumscribed]

---

> ***Q***. Is some inscribed radius equal to some circumscribed radius,
> among all the gap-filling circles?
> Is ever a blue circle congruent to a red circle? Or do they each generate
> distinct infinite series of radii that never share a radius?

I would especially appreciate a resolution without resorting to explicit calculation
of every radius.

Comment: If you look at the primary "chain" of circles (i.e. touching the perimeter of the segment or triangle),the sequences of positions and radii are recurrent.  There are similarities with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591844/chain-of-circles-internally-tangent-to-an-ellipse/3640977#3640977, a question a chain of circles in an ellipse.  There the answer is less about geometry and more about the properties of Lucas sequences.  I speculate that it is a similar story here, albeit more complicated because we're dealing with more than just the primary chains.