# Are there any interesting geometric generating sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

I am considering ways in which geometric shapes - governed in some way by any particular mathematical object - could be generated in some sequence of unique figures, ideally infinite, but circumscribed to a small area, for the sake of visibility.

Here’s what I mean. I remember in one class we saw different diffraction patterns when I think two sources of oscillation were near to each other. I can’t remember what the dependent variable was, but as it was incremented, all kinds of new, interesting diffraction patterns in 2d space appeared, and it seemed like this went on infinitely.

Except, I am more interested in what we ordinarily think of as shapes - squares, the hourglass shape, a circle, a figure 8, a triangle, and more complicated nested figures.

It does not have to produce these exact shapes, but the wish is to be able to generate a sequence of unique forms, ad infinitum. I would say the only real constraint is it has to fit in a unitary square around the origin. The type of form can be anything, even though I prefer linear shapes. Also, the sequence could be subscripted to skip over some repetitive cases.

Comment: We can of course have the sequence of regular $n$-gons, or forms of $n$-pointed stars. But I guess you're looking for more variety.

Comment: Maybe this?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591844/chain-of-circles-internally-tangent-to-an-ellipse/3640977#3640977